# REST API curl POST

Tags: curl, post

I am using this command to send REST API request through curl, but i get error.

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Accept: */*" \
    -H "Content-Length: 101" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=sftp-backup&client_secret=6f5328f2-d5d3-4600-9daf-378001bae0dd" \
    "https://x.x.x.x/auth/realms/cbam/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

`{"error_description":"Invalid client secret","error":"unauthorized_client"}`

Answer (score 0):

The error response seems quite clear. Check if both the clientid and client secret are same as registered with the Identity provider.